# aligning splitted 3D scans

Tags: geometry

Spent the whole day trying to solve this problem of mine so I decided to ask for help.
I have two 3D scans of the very same building. Since one part of the building is of low quality I made another scan of that part wich is of good quality. I now want to replace the bad part with the good, combining the two scans.
 The scans is of the very same building but the meshes differs somehow since they are cut at different places (more ground etc). 
The placement in the 3D space, rotation and scaling is also different. Therefore it is quite a hard task to align the meshes since it involves 3D rotation, scaling and transforming all at once. 
Does Blender have any tool that might be able to align the meshes in a simpler way? The meshes contains a lot of patterns etc. that could be used as references.
[image]

So in short. Is it possible to align and scale two (almost) identical objects given reference information in the objects themselves?

I know there is a software called Meshlab  that can do this, but I dislike that software since it cannot undo it's operations and it crashes very often. If anyone got any helps I would be greatful..
Thanks for your time!
Regards